# Multiple tailwindcss configurations do not work in Next.js v13

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css, next.js13

I am working on an ecommerce Next.js app with a website and dashboard. The styles and configurations for my Next.js app in the website and dashboard are different, so I need two Tailwind CSS configurations.I created two Tailwind CSS configuration files based on the Tailwind CSS documentation and my research online. However, when I add `font-interRegualr` or colors in the dashboard, the configurations I added in `tailwind.dashboard.config.js` do not apply to the dashboard.And also, in the VSCode IntelliSense, it doesn't show configurations from `tailwind.dashboard.config.js`.

**tailwind.dashboard.css**

```
@config "../../tailwind.dashboard.config.js";

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

---

**tailwind.dashboard.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/dashboard/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/dashboard/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],

  theme: {
    screens: {
      xs: { max: "639px" },
      ...defaultTheme.screens,
    },
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },

      fontFamily: {
        interRegular: ["var(--font-interRegular)", "sans-serif"],
        interSemibold: ["var(--font-interSemiBold)", "sans-serif"],
      },
      fontSize: {
        48: "48px",
        24: "24px",
        18: "18px",
        14: "14px",
        12: "12px",
      },
      colors: {
        // black: {
        //   900: "#1c1c1c",
        //   80: "#1C1C1CCC",
        //   40: "#1C1C1C66",
        //   20: "#1C1C1C33",
        //   10: "#1C1C1C1A",
        //   5: "#1C1C1C0D",
        // },
        black: {
          50: "#E8E8E8",
          100: "#DEDEDE",
          200: "#C7C7C7",
          300: "#B0B0B0",
          400: "#999999",
          500: "#828282",
          600: "#6B6B6B",
          700: "#545454",
          800: "#3D3D3D",
          900: "#262626",
          950: "#1C1C1C",
        },
        white: {
          100: "#FFFFFF",
          80: "#FFFFFFCC",
          40: "#FFFFFF66",
          20: "#FFFFFF33",
          10: "#FFFFFF1A",
          5: "#FFFFFF0D",
        },
        primary: {
          light: "#F7F9FB",
          blue: "#E3F5FF",
          purple: "#E5ECF6",
          purple50: "#E5ECF680",
          brand: "#1c1c1c",
        },
        secondary: {
          purpleA: "#95A4FC",
          purpleB: "#C6C7F8",
          blueA: "#A8C5DA",
          blueB: "#E3F5FF",
          greenA: "#A1E3CB",
          greenB: "#BAEDBD",
          yellow: "#FFE999",
          red: "#FF4747",
        },
      },
    },
  },

  plugins: [],
};
```

---

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "./src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "!./src/components/dashboard/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
    "!./src/app/dashboard/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}",
  ],

  theme: {
    screens: {
      xs: { max: "639px" },
      ...defaultTheme.screens,
    },
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        "gradient-radial": "radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
        "gradient-conic":
          "conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))",
      },
      minWidth: {
        "1140px": "71.25rem",
      },
      maxWidth: {
        90: "90rem",
        "1380px": "86.25rem",
      },
      fontFamily: {
        jostBodyBold: ["var(--font-jostBold)", "sans-serif"],
        jostBodyRegular: ["var(--font-jostRegular)", "sans-serif"],
      },
      fontSize: {
        16: "16px",
        14: "14px",
        241: "241.38px",
      },
      fontWeight: {
        400: 400,
        700: 700,
      },
      lineHeight: {
        23: "23px",
      },
      dropShadow: {
        boxShadow: "0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)",
      },
      borderRadius: {
        10: "10px",
      },
      spacing: {
        "30px": "1.875rem",
        "13.5px": "0.8437rem",
        "5px": "0.3125rem",
        "122.5px": "7.65rem",
        "16.5px": "1.03rem",
      },
      width: {
        "70px": "70px",
        8625: "86.25rem",
      },
      height: {
        "70px": "70px",
      },

      colors: {
        primary: {
          100: "#A29FA9",
          200: "#8D8A94",
          300: "#77757C",
          400: "#575360",
          500: "#131118",
          600: "#14111C",
          700: "#14111C",
          800: "#14111C",
          900: "#14111C",
        },
        secondary: {
          100: "#E1F1BC",
          200: "#CEE993",
          300: "#BCDE6B",
          400: "#AFD751",
          500: "#A3D139",
          600: "#97BD33",
          700: "#88A52A",
          800: "#798D21",
          900: "#626615",
        },
        tertiary: {
          100: "#F0B0D9",
          200: "#E67BC2",
          300: "#D846AB",
          400: "#CD0D9B",
          500: "#B21589",
          600: "#AF0A87",
          700: "#9B0982",
          800: "#8A087C",
          900: "#6C0772",
        },
        dark: "#131118",
        dark5: "#1311180D",
        dark600: "#14111C",
        dark90: "#131118E8",
        gray: "#A4A1AA",
        grayOpacity: "#A4A1AA33",
        light: "#D9E1E1",
        white: "#FFFFFF",
      },
    },
  },

  plugins: [],
};
```

---

**DashboardLayout**

```
import "@/styles/tailwind.dashboard.css";
import Sidebar from "@/components/dashboard/presentational/Sidebar";
import Navbar from "@/components/dashboard/presentational/Navbar";
const DashboardLayout = function ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html className="h-full bg-white">
      <body className="h-full font-interRegular">
        <Sidebar />
        <div className="lg:pl-72 text-zinc-900">
          <Navbar />
          <main className="py-10">
            <div className="px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8"> {children}</div>
          </main>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};
export default DashboardLayout;
```